# I want to build the Dockerfile that is in parent directory

Tags: gradle

I'm using gradle [docker plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin) for building dockerfiles.

my workding directory tree is as bellow:

```
test/
├── build.gradle.kts
├── buildSrc
├── Dockerfile
├── gradle
├── gradle.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── mini
└── settings.gradle.kts
```

I want to build mini but the Dockerfile is in parent directory (and it has to be there):

```
tasks.register<DockerBuildImage>("dockerBuild") {
      inputDir.set(layout.projectDirectory)
      dockerFile.set(layout.projectDirectory.dir("..").file("Dockerfile"))
}
```

but when I run this it get me Error:

> Status 500: {"message":"Cannot locate specified Dockerfile:
> /home/mine/gradle/test/Dockerfile"}

but the file exists exactly in that path.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle 8.0.1 at least seems to support it.

Not sure which version you're using, but this is what works for me, using slightly different pattern to build the path.

```
task buildMyAppImage(type: DockerBuildImage) {
    doNotTrackState("Input file outside of project")
    inputDir.set(projectDir)
    dockerFile.set(new File("$projectDir/../Dockerfile"))
}
```